# EF code first, one to (zero or many)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I maybe thinking about this completely wrong and could explain why I can't find an answer on google but, can you have a one to (zero or many) relationship in EF code first?

Example

```
public class Item1
{
     public int Id {get;set;}

     public virtual ICollection<Item2> Item2List {get;set;}
}

public class Item2
{
     public int Id {get;set;}

     public int Item1Id {get;set;}

     public virtual Item1 Item1 {get;set;}
}
```

So from the above I would like the rules to be this.

- `Item1` can have many or zero `Item2` and does not require any when being
  added to the database.
- If `Item1` is deleted then it cascades to any anything in `Item2List`.
- `Item2` requires 1 `Item1`.
- If `Item2` is deleted then it does not affect `Item1`.

EDIT:

Running the above the migration created is this

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.Item1",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Item2",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Item1Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Item1", t => t.Item1Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.Item1Id);
```

again, this maybe my misunderstanding but does `.ForeignKey("dbo.Item1", t => t.Item1Id, cascadeDelete: true)` mean when you delete `Item2` delete `Item1` as well? or have I got this wrong and does this mean, when `Item1` is deleted then delete `Item2`?

Comment: What have you tried, please?

Comment: By default EF conventions, the model as posted will produce exactly what you want. Note that `1 => 0..N` is usually referred as `one-to-many`

Comment: Your code configures a one to many relationship. It should work. Is there an issue with it?

Comment: @AmanvirSinghMundra see my edit. Could just be a misunderstanding thing.

Comment: That means when you delete Item1, then the related Item2s get deleted as well. If you don't want to cascade then just make Item1 foreign key as nullable.

Comment: @AmanvirSinghMundra now I see why its ok as it is, makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

you can done this using fluent api like this

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Item2>()
                .HasOptional<Item1>(s => s.Item1 ) 
                .WithMany(s => s.Item2List).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

but you need to edit your foreign key to allow null like this

```
public int? Item1Id{get;set;}
```

Comment: It has to be HasRequired and WillCascadeOnDelete( true )

Comment: i have added edit to allow null as he want to make it zero or many so it's not required

Comment: cite from q: *Item2 requires 1 Item1*

Comment: does `modelBuilder.Entity<Item2>().HasOptional<Item1>(s => s.Item1 )` mean `Item2` has optional `Item1`? should this not be changed to HasRequired?

Comment: I am very sure that *HasOptional* means *has optional* ;o)